# Delete a row from Quip spreadsheet using Python API

Tags: quip, bulk-delete

I have a requirement to delete all rows in a Quip spreadsheet and reload the data. However, it seems that this is not possible with the existing API commands. Therefore, I have looked into the [edit_command]([https://github.com/quip/quip-api/blob/master/python/quip.py#:~:text=def%20edit_document(self%2C%20thread_id%2C%20content%2C%20operation%3DAPPEND%2C%20format%3D%22html%22%2C)](https://github.com/quip/quip-api/blob/master/python/quip.py#:%7E:text=def%20edit_document(self%2C%20thread_id%2C%20content%2C%20operation%3DAPPEND%2C%20format%3D%22html%22%2C)) method to delete the data based on the row ID. I passed None to the content argument and row id to the section_id argument. However, it didn't delete the row from the Quip spreadsheet. Can someone please suggest what should be passed to the content argument in this case? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Below is the command I am executing
client.edit_document(document_id,None, "DELETE_SECTION", format="markdown",section_id ='temp:s:temp:C:URSe6c5fdef98c642d1bf0372f41_temp:C:URS9a7c4c6065204bdc9f0ad036b')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.